# System.IO.FileNotFoundException Error while refrencing a .net standard library inside a .net framework project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-standard

I'm getting `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` error while trying to add a .net standard library into .net framework project's references.

I have created a .net standard project which contains some other .net standard nuggets in its references, and it's output is a dll which I have inserted it as a reference in a .net framework library (actually it is a unit test project for it). But as I told before it always show me this error:

> Message: Test method xDetector.Test.IntegreatedTest.TestMethod threw
>   exception:  System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'xFramework.NetCore.xDetector, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

I have try several ways like editing `cproj` file and adding other changing visual studio version (which currently is 2019) but no success.

Where the problem may come from?

Comment: The program cannot find the filename on the system,  It is not a library issue.  You are try to find a file by its name.

Comment: Is the `'xFramework.NetCore.xDetector` assembly referenced within your unit test project? I.e. have you installed the nuget for it in both projects?

Comment: do you get this error in runtime or compiletime? please provide target frameworks for both projects.